# Understanding an mobile app is native or hybrid

Tags: android, ios, native, mobile-application, hybrid

How can I find an app is native or hybrid?

I have `.ipa` or `.apk` file.

Comment: This is a really good post which might help you: http://www.kinvey.com/blog/3421/how-to-spot-a-hybrid-app-on-ios

Comment: Check this http://www.mobiloud.com/blog/2012/06/native-web-or-hybrid-apps/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My app, [App Detective](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zmarties.detective), will show you the contents of apps that you've installed on your Android device, so you can easily see if the app contains HTML files, and whether it uses Java packages such as PhoneGap/Cordova which are used to power hybrid apps.

Answer (score 1):

if you can't realize this from UI, for web based hybrid apps you can extract .apk file and look for .html .js files under assets folder if there are some .html .js files then you have a web based hybrid application

Answer (score 0):

as mohammad R. said, just try to extract it with zip extractor like 7zip or others.
if it is hybrid, it will have WWW folder with .html file.. www folder can also be named as app or public. If it is .jar then it is native